# optimize command with or and pipe to parse the output of ifconfig

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, pipe, ifconfig

I have this command line, but it's doubling the `grep` and `awk`

```
ifconfig eth1 2> /dev/null | grep "inet " | awk '{gsub("addr:","",$2);  print $2 }' ||
ifconfig eth0 2> /dev/null | grep "inet " | awk '{gsub("addr:","",$2);  print $2 }'`
```

I have being trying to shorten this by doing something like,

```
echo $(ifconfig eth1 2> /dev/null || ifconfig eth0 2> /dev/null) &>  grep "inet " |
awk '{gsub("addr:","",$2);  print $2 }'
```

but it returns nothing at all when I am looking to get the IP of server.  What is the best way to say get info if on error try this and then pipe it to `grep`

Comment: Please add OS/distribution and version.

Comment: I'm testing on a CentOS box but I'd like it to be as universal as I can

Comment: See: [Deprecated Linux networking commands and their replacements](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/). A default installation of RHEL7 has no ifconfig.

Comment: @cyrus, so should I have a `ip a || ` as well in there?

Comment: or forget `ifconfig` and use `ip`.

Comment: got an idea on how that command would work?  or what the awk would be?  i run a `ip a` and get a list of  `lo` `eth0` and on another `lo` `eth1`

Comment: Btw: probably not portable, works with CentOS, RHEL and Ubuntu: `hostname -I` (large i)

Comment: I will run with that.. it's more portable you mean?  way smaller for sure..

Comment: I meant that `hostname -I` probably is not portable. I've tested it only with RHEL6,7, Ubuntu 11.04 and 14.04. RHEL5's `hostname` has no option `-I`.

Comment: @Cyrus got ya, I will then need to run down the `ip a` approach then i would suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ ( ifconfig eth2 2>/dev/null || ifconfig eth0 2>/dev/null ) | grep ...
```

It has the same logic, but it does the `||` inside the parens so it only passes the output of the successful command to `grep`.

Comment: `$ ( ifconfig eth2 2>/dev/null || ifconfig eth0 2>/dev/null ) | grep "inet " | awk '{gsub("addr:","",$2);  print $2 }'` returns `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `ifconfig'`

Comment: what version of bash?

Comment: 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)  but I'd like it to be as universal as I can

Comment: The `$` is not part of the command. Just `( ifconfig eth2 2>/dev/null || ifconfig eth0 2>/dev/null ) | grep ...`

Comment: Correct - the `$` is the prompt. The command you type in starts with the `(`.

Comment: aw.. ok yeah that works now.. question now is which is safer, this or http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/214241/47672 .. this one is longer, but I know there is an or going on.. the other works as well but I am not seeing logic directly in the command and not 100% it'd be correct..

Answer (score 2):

Another more modular approach: not bash-specific

```
get_ifconfig () { 
    for iface do 
        ifconfig "$iface" 2>/dev/null && return
    done
}
get_ifconfig eth1 eth2 eth3 | sed -n 's/.*inet addr:\([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: this is on the command line not in a file

Comment: It's OK to define functions on the command line. You can paste this code directly to a shell prompt.

Comment: in this case i need it in one line

Comment: @jeremy.bass Then replace the newlines by semicolons, except the one after `do`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach

```
$ echo eth1 eth0 | xargs -n 1 ifconfig 2>/dev/null | awk '/inet/{gsub("addr:","",$2);print $2;exit}'
192.168.124.132
$
```

Comment: I end up with `addr:10.255.255.3
addr:
addr:10.0.2.15
addr:`  I should only end up with `10.255.255.3`

Comment: `echo eth1 eth0 | xargs -n 1 ifconfig 2>/dev/null | grep "inet " | awk '{gsub("addr:","",$2);  print $2 }'` is a little closer but it should be that if `eth1` doesn't have a value go look to `eth0` right now it's still getting both

Comment: Now edited to fix (added gsub and the exit).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab the first interface that has an IPv4 address, you can run `ifconfig` just once to display all the interfaces and extract the first entry with an IPv4 address. You can also optimize the extraction by combining what you're doing with `grep` and `awk`.

```
ifconfig -a | awk '/^[^ ]/ {iface=$1}
                  iface ~ /^eth/ && sub(/inet addr:/,"") {print $1; exit}'
```

The newline is optional, I included it for clarity. This is a more elaborate version of

```
ifconfig -a | awk 'sub(/inet addr:/,"") {print $1; exit}'
```

which might print something like `127.0.0.1` (from the loopback interface) that you presumably don't want.

If you prefer to use `ip`, parsing is about equally awkward.

```
ip addr | awk '/^[0-9]/ {iface=$2}
               iface ~ /^eth/ && $1 == "inet" {sub(/\/.*/, "", $2); print $2}'
```